# Rails 2.3.5: how to get routes name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my applications routes.rb I have defined three routes like the following

```
 map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
 map.login  '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
 map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
```

Is it possible for me to get the controller and action name for a particular path?

I am looking for some method like this...

```
def current_routes(a)
end
```

should return `:controller => 'users', :action => 'new'`  if I call `current_routes('signup_path')`

Comment: Maybe `rake routes` in what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path("/posts/")
```

If you only have a string with your route (like "signup_path"), then I guess in the context you're using this you should be able to do

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(send("signup_path".to_sym))
```

Comment: When i use ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(send("signup_path".to_sym))
it gives me undefined method `signup_path' error. But i have defined that in my routes and if i try .to_s for the one of route in console i get 
ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes[1].to_s
=> "ANY    /signup/                                 {:action=>\"new\", :controller=>\"users\"}"

Comment: I guess from console you cant get access of helper methods like signup_path. Try it from UI.

Comment: @ssri   The same approach does not work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42691729/1610034), any thoughts?