# Rails, how to get the route name from the actual request (routing reverse lookup)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I have the actual **request** and I would like to know the **name of the route** that Rails has resolved.

For example, if I have this route:

```
front_page GET    /front/pages/:id(.:format)
```

And the actual request is:

```
/front/pages/10 (GET)
```

I would like to have as result:

```
front_page
```

Comment: There are similar questions in SO like http://stackoverflow.com/q/1203892/316700 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5231027/316700 but the are not returning the **route name**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you could use the code explained by KinOfCain on [How can I find out the current route in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203892/how-can-i-find-out-the-current-route-in-rails)

```
Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request){ |route, matches, parameters| puts route.name }
```

The router is not storing the route recognized in any place at least I wasn't able to find it

Comment: @fguillen   The same approach does not work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42691729/1610034), any thoughts?